# How to enable a linkbutton server control using javascript?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I have a linkbutton server control in my page whose Enabled attribute is initially set to "false". When a text box's text changes I would like to enable the linkbutton. I tried the following but it does not work. Could you let me know if i am missing something.

```
function TextBox_TextChanged()
{
    var control = $get("<%= linkButtonSave.ClientID%>");
    if(control != null)
        control.enabled = true;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try

```
control.disabled = false;
```

You're dealing with HTML controls, not server side controls.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to use an id selector. And remove the disabled attribute using `.removeAttr()`. I assume you are using `$get` as an alias name for `$`.

```
$get("#<%= linkButtonSave.ClientID%>").removeAttr("disabled");
```